# UITextView with magnifying-glass and no keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

When using a `UITextView` one usually gets a keyboard to edit the contents; and by touching it one also gets a magnifying glass to help bring the cursor in the desired position. **Is it possible to get the magnifying glass to position the cursor but at the same time eliminate the keyboard?**

Comment: Please edit the title of your post to reflect the question that you have. As it is, the title is pretty ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. Try this

```
textView.inputView = [UIView new]
```